# Error on basic usage of osm2pgsql

Tags: osm2pgsql

I need only basic `osm2pgsql` usage. Using *postgres* user and *sandbox*  (created) database.

```
   sudo -u postgres osm2pgsql -s -U postgres -d sandbox brazil-latest.osm.pbf
```

---

### NOTES

Using UBUNTU 14 LTS, `osm2pgsql --version` say "osm2pgsql SVN version 0.82.0 (64bit id space)". At SQL terminal (psql) the `select version()` says "9.3.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".

Prepare, all steps:

```
wget -c http://download.geofabrik.de/south-america/brazil-latest.osm.pbf

wget -c http://download.geofabrik.de/south-america/brazil-latest.osm.pbf.md5

md5sum -c brazil-latest.osm.pbf.md5
# OK

sudo -u postgres psql sandbox
# ...     SELECT PostGIS_version();  -- 2.1 OK
\q

sudo -u postgres osm2pgsql -s -U postgres -d sandbox brazil-latest.osm.pbf
```

last command errors:

```
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.82.0 (64bit id space)

Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_line" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_line_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_roads" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_roads_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Out of memory for node cache dense index, try using "--cache-strategy sparse" instead 
Error occurred, cleaning up
```

Try also `sudo -u postgres osm2pgsql --create --cache-strategy sparse -s -U postgres -d sandbox brazil-latest.osm.pbf`  but some error: *"Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Out of memory for sparse node cache, reduce --cache size
Error occurred, cleaning up
"*

Try also `osm2pgsql -c -d sandbox -U postgres -H localhost -S brazil-latest.osm.pbf`  that say *"Usage error"*.

Try also `osm2pgsql -U postgres --slim -C 20000 -d sandbox --host localhost --number-processes 20 ./brazil-latest.osm.pbf`
but *"Error: Connection to database failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied"*.

`sudo -u postgres osm2pgsql -U postgres --slim -C 20000 -d sandbox --host localhost --number-processes 20 ./brazil-latest.osm.pbf`  say *"Error: Connection to database failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied"*.

Comment: Maybe the -C 20000 is too high, and the system cannot allocate 20GB or memory. Try to lower such number

Comment: I found out a **osm2pgsql** usage that it worked for me. See my answer.

Comment: Hi @GiacomoCatenazzi your clue about `-C` option is correct (!), I try with `-C 2000`  (same error) them `-C 200` and it works!   It is a 1GB RAM DigitalOcean servelet.

Comment: @xunilk, you say "See my answer", do you have a link?  ... Well now I found [help.openstreetmap.org/5956](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/5956/how-much-ram-does-osm2pgsql-need), [help.openstreetmap.org/8322](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/8322/osm2pgsql-import-getting-killed-as-relations-are-processed).

Comment: My answer, of course, in your question in **gis.stackexchange.com**: "Error on basic usage of osm2pgsql". I didn't use --slim parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I used the **osm2pgsql** command (installed with synaptic) in my Debian system in a different way. After creating and connecting the **sandbox** database (at a bash console):

```
su
********* [password]
su - postgres
psql
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE sandbox OWNER my_owner;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \connect sandbox
You are now connected to database "sandbox" as user "postgres".
```

I created **postgis** and **hstore** extensions with these instructions:

```
sandbox=#CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION
sandbox=# CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

The last one extension implements the hstore data type for storing sets of key/value pairs within a single PostgreSQL value. This is especially useful when you are working with OpenStreetMap data.

After downloading **brazil-latest.osm.pbf**, as it was specified above, I used this command (in a bash console):

```
osm2pgsql -d sandbox -s -W --hstore brazil-latest.osm.pbf
```

to load the layers to **sandbox** database.

An extract of all process at the bash console (my password was required):

```
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.86.0 (64bit id space)

Password:
Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
.
.
.

Reading in file: brazil-latest.osm.pbf
Processing: Node(35458k 124.9k/s) Way(3307k 8.82k/s) Relation(71370 41.45/s)  parse time: 2381s
.
.
.
Stopped table: planet_osm_ways in 2613s

Osm2pgsql took 5697s overall
```

After finished the process, I loaded the **planet_osm_polygon** layer by using 'Add PostGIS Layers' button in the 'Manage Layers Toolbar' of QGIS:

[image]

It works!

Comment: Thanks, you show a lot more context and steps (!).  Well, about the question, the key answer is `-C`  option, that must be compatible with the RAM of the server. The only command that run on my 1Gb RAM was `sudo -u postgres osm2pgsql -C 400 --slim --cache-strategy sparse -s -U postgres -d sandbox brazil-latest.osm.pbf`

Answer (score 1):

The errors are clear. On first you don't have enough memory, so you should use `--slim` (but you should do this in any case, if you want to update the data).

The last errors are database connection error. Check again the configuration of database and permissions of the user.

Note: if you installed a new version of postgresql (over a ond one, in Debian and ubuntu), the database engine uses a new port number, so try to give explicitly a port number.

Comment: Yes, see "NOTES" I used... The best try with slim was `sudo -u postgres osm2pgsql --slim -s -U postgres -d sandbox brazil-latest.osm.pbf` that, as error, suggested to use "--cache-strategy sparse"... Adding cache option, `sudo -u postgres osm2pgsql --cache-strategy sparse --slim -s -U postgres -d sandbox brazil-latest.osm.pbf`, where   the error is *"Allocating memory for sparse node cache\n Out of memory for sparse node cache, reduce --cache size"*

Comment: What is "new version of postgresql"?  I am using pg9.3.9 (as "select version()" say), so, if it is "new", what the *port* number?

Comment: I imported the entire planet with --slim and -C 12000 (which are much less then yours, and for a larger area), so I tend to think there is an other error. I used also "--input-reader pbf" and --style ... , but these should have given you an other error.

Comment: The first version of postgresql will use port  5432, but when you install a new version (sometime also because an update, and during update the other port is still used), the new server will use 5433 or successive ports.